# Examples on how to declare Caffe LSTM?

Tags: caffe, lstm

Caffe seems to have an LSTM layer now:

http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers/lstm.html

However, there is no documentation on how to use it. How would I declare the following LSTM layer with the new API?

```
layer {
  name: "lstm1"
  type: "Lstm"
  bottom: "data"
  bottom: "clip"
  top: "lstm1"

  RecurrentParameter {
    num_output: 15
    clipping_threshold: 0.1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.1
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
```